# Reversing a String in MASM. Getting a strange output

Tags: assembly, output, reverse, masm, irvine32

I am trying to reverse a string in my assembly language class. I believe that I have the correct code, but the output is only "a". Here is the code:

```
; Reverses an input string of at least 10 characters
; Author:  Nathan Smith
; Created: 10/26/2018
; Revisions:
; Date:             Modified by:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
myString BYTE "abcdefghij", 0       ; original string
temp BYTE ?                         ; temporary string holder

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, SIZEOF myString    ; source index register
    mov ecx, SIZEOF myString    ; loop counter
    movzx eax, myString         ; moves string to temp holder
    mov temp, al
    mov edi, 0                  ; destination index register
L1:
    mov al, temp[esi]           ; moves last letter to al
    mov myString[edi], al       ; moves letter from al to myString
    dec esi                     ; decreases pointer by 1
    inc edi                     ; increases destination pointer by 1
    loop L1                     ; repeat for length of string

    mov edx, OFFSET myString
    call WriteString
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: I think you are confusing a pointer to a string and a string. You allocated a singly byte for `temp` but read from that memory location as if there is more than 1 byte of data.. `movzx eax, myString` moves the first byte of `myString` into eax and zero extends the value to fill EAX.

Comment: yeah but assembler doesn't have a term `string`. May be it's better not to explain at all. It's about that  variable name cant point to another thing then its initial place. It's not C or so.

Comment: Even if I change to `mov al, myString`, it does the same thing.

Comment: @ndsmith Rewrite it all in old style

Answer (score 0):

The length of string needs to account for zero indexing so;

```
mov   esi, SIZEOF myString - 1         ; Should equal 8
mov   ecx, SIZEOF myString             ; Should equal 9
```

The terminating character 0x0 **NULL** needs to be written to the end of *temp*. In an effort to optimize at least a little, writing 4 NULLs works as EDI is only a 32 bit register.

```
xor   edi, edi
mov   temp[ecx],edi                    ; Writing 4 chars

; Instead of

mov   BYTE temp[ecx], 0
```

The only thing that needs change in your loop is;

```
@@:
mov   al, myString [edi]               ; Read char from source
mov   temp[esi], al                    ; and write to destination
dec   esi
inc   edi
loop  @B
```

What was happening with your program is that

```
movzx eax, myString
mov   temp, al
```

Was moving first character of source to first position of destination and because you failed to account for zero indexing, the terminating character from source was the next thing written to *temp.*

Comment: If you use a different register for the counter that needs to be zeroed, `mov temp[ecx], dl` is efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes OP's code has copious amounts of bloat, I tried not to deviate to far from the intent of the question. I did do an example just for my own interest that came in at 23 bytes vs 57 of the original post.

Comment: Yeah.  But since you were mentioning changes, you don't need to do a dword store that includes 3 bytes past the end of what you'd otherwise write.  Anyway, you forgot another major bug: the OP's `temp BYTE ?` only has a 1 byte buffer for the destination.